# What is the level of politeness for 我々?

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes hear 我々{われわれ} and 私{わたし}たち for "we", but am at a loss for understanding when I should use one over the other. Any tips?

Comment: There are 僕たち, 俺たち, 俺ら, うちら, 我ら, and [私]{わたくし}ども as well.

Comment: @nodakai Not to mention 僕ら and あたし達.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are synonymous in meaning.

"我々" is more suitable in settings like political speeches (when referring to a group, including the speaker). It can have a strict and also archaic ring to it.

"私達" can also be read as "わたくしたち", which is highly formal. It might be suitable in a setting like a wedding reception, where you are referring to your spouse and yourself.

[from goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/5452/meaning/m0u/)

> [使い分け]
>
> 【１】「私達」は、話し言葉でも書き言葉でも用いる。
>
> 【２】「私達」は、「わたしたち」ともいうが、「わたくしたち」の方が、より改まった言い方。
>
> 【３】「我々」は、文語的で硬い言い方。

---

Otherwise, I can say I have heard people at my company use it, when referring to the company as a group, as opposed to an outside group (like a client). In this setting, the people saying it are also usually all men. It might be the preference of some men to avoid the word "私{わたし}" as it can be considered feminine.

Answer (score 5):

我々 is literary and hard word. We don't use it commonly but is sometimes used in oration.

私たち is commonly used.